# Set margin for html body dynamically by obtaining viewport width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set margin of the id:main dynamically by obtaining viewport width. I have numerous blocks of same width in the page. So, i want to fit as many blocks as possible and centre them by dynamically calculating the remaining width. the block is of size 240px, 20px of padding

I have tried two codes, i'm stuck at this for a while.

```
var width=$(window).width()
var stickies=Math.floor(width/240);  //* calculate how many can fit in a row
var mrg=(width-(stickies*240)-20);//*calculating remaining width 
var mrg=(width-(stickies*240)-20)/2;
var el1=$('#main');
var el2=$('#main');
el1.css('margin-left',mrg+'px');
el2.css('margin-right',mrg+'px'); 



var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,g=d.getElementsByTagName('body')     [0],x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||g.clientWidth;
var stickies=Math.floor(var x/240);
var mrg=(var x-(var stickies*240)-20)/2;
var el1=$('#main');
var el2=$('#main');
el1.css('margin-left',mrg+'px');
el2.css('margin-right',mrg+'px');
```

Comment: `$(#main)` will give you a syntax error.. it should be `$('#main')`

Comment: pebbl, thank you. even then its not helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Version

you should need something along those lines

```
var width=$(window).width();
var stickies=Math.floor(width/240);  //* calculate how many can fit in a row
var mrg=(width-(stickies*240)-20)/2; //*calculating remaining width 
$('#main').css({'margin-left': mrg+'px', 'margin-right': mrg+'px'});
```

### Long Version

your code needs a lot of fixing up.

```
var el1=$(#main);
```

needs to change to

```
var el1=$('#main');
```

because at the moment u are not selecting anything. you need to place your selector in quotes.

---

also i dont understand why u are using 2 variables for the same element. you could do something like

```
$('#main').css({'margin-left': mrg+'px', 'margin-right': mrg+'px'});
```

or something along those lines.

---

Finally,

```
var mrg=(width-(stickies*240)-20);//*calculating remaining width 
var mrg=(width-(stickies*240)-20)/2;
```

The 2nd line will overwrite the 1st line. Is this a typo or are you trying to do something here?

Comment: thank you. No, its not a typo, i was unable to see so small text while posting. I'm figuring out, there's still something missing

Comment: im still unable to figure out which part has a bug